# Elegant way for  "where" clause by vector?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, where-clause

table :

```
name |   isActive       //(bit -  not nullable)
___________________
a          1
b          1
c          0
d          0
...        ...
```

in the UI I have this :

[image]

the user can select if he wantd only the `Active ones` , `Non Active ones` , `Nothing`

Im creating a vector which can have one of these values : `'11,10,01,00'`

> 10 = give me the active  , dont give me - non actives
>
> 01 = give me the non active  , dont give me - actives
>
> 11  give me both ...
>
> 00  nothing ...

this is the start .

but im looking for the most **elegant** way of the `where` clause in my query :

my shoot :

```
select ...
WHERE  isActive = CASE  WHEN LEFT(@vector, 1) = RIGHT(@vector, 1)
       AND RIGHT(@vector, 1) = '1' THEN isActive
         ELSE 
          ... ( more option calculations ( bad and long and non elegant ...)

           END
```

**any elegant help ?**

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `WHERE active = 1 (or 0)`?

Comment: @Lieven sometimes poepole wants a report with both 1   , 0

Comment: I'm probably still not seeing the whole picture but in that case you'll just ommit the where clause alltogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what do you mean by `00 - NOTHING`. Actually, it means that you don't need to execute the query.
You can try this:

```
...
WHERE isActive=@isActive OR @isActive IS NULL
```

When you care about `isActive` you pass `1` or `0` to `@isActive`, when you don't you pass `NULL`.

But this query will not use indexes over `isActive`.

Comment: I dont know if I pass. Im passing to sql what the vector from c#. i.e : if 10 / 01 then your query is fine.  but if 1/1 it is not.

Comment: the only situation is 0/0 which  I dont need to execute none. you right. what about 1/1 ? Im not passing NULL im passing 11

Comment: @RoyiNamir You can change logic of the application to use `@isActive` as `bit`, but if you can not then you can use `NULLIF(@isActive,'1/1')` function.